# Merge tables Excel (Parent and Child ID)

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have a problem to merge two tables with excel.
I have one table called Father with a numeric value and to that ID there can be a lot of sons with other values. I want to create a third table with the numeric value from the father and the names of the sons and their father id.

I'm not sure how to explain it better so I created a small EXCEL file to demonstrate. The orange table is the one I want to create and the blue ones are my orignal.

[FatherSonID_ExcelExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UBWi.png)

I have created a macro in VBA but it's very ineffcient and my father/son tables contains several thousand of values and I need a faster way create the table. So hopefully somebody have a much faster way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any relationship between father and son in your example, and how come there are 2 fathers with the same id? Are the father and son tables held in mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming if you have an inefficient and time consuming VBA Macro to solve this problem, you are probably doing something along the lines of:

```
Dim Rng1 as Range, Rng2 as Range
For X = 1 to 10000
    For Y = 1 to 10000
        If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value then
                Do Something
        End If
    Next Y
Next X
```

You should try and speed it up by doing something like this instead:

```
Dim Fathers as Variant, Sons as Variant
Fathers = Range("A1:A10000").Value 'Substitute for your actual range of Father IDs
Sons = Range("B1:B10000").Value 'Substitute for your actual range of Son IDs

For X = 1 to UBound(Fathers, 1)
    For Y = 1 to UBound(Sons, 1)
        If Sons(Y, 1) = Fathers(X, Y) then
                Do Something
        End If
    Next Y
Next X
```

It doesn’t look like a big change, but you will find that by defining an Array of values and then doing operations on that array, you will dramatically reduce the time for those operations.